# joining a list together with index's

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, indexing

I have been working on a bucket sort algorithm.

might be simple but how would I join these buckets(index's) together without interrupting the second list.

```
list1 = [[], ['aa', 'aa'], [], ['bbbb', 'bbbb']]
```

hidden in test file:

```
list2 = [[], ['aa', 'aa']]
```

the result I am after is:

```
list1 = ['aa', 'aa', 'bbbb', 'bbbb']
list2 = ['aa', 'aa']
```

I have managed to sort these lists by size but unable to put them into a single list without interrupting list2. as the index would be out of range.

thanks guys.

Answer (score 3):

To join the elements of such a list simply use

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(list1))
['aa', 'aa', 'bbbb', 'bbbb']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add/concatinate them.

```
list1 = [[], ['aa', 'aa'], [], ['bbbb', 'bbbb']]
finishlist = []
for element in list1:
    finishlist = finishlist + element

print(finishlist)
```

output:

```
['aa', 'aa', 'bbbb', 'bbbb']
```

Comment: This would be more efficient with `finishlist.extend(element)` (and the length check is superfluous really)

Comment: I'm not convinced extend is more efficient based on various tests I've done, but you're right the length wasn't required and I edited and removed it.

Comment: The effect will be immeasurable for tiny lists ... try a simple test of a list of a hundred lists of a hundred items for example.  Then eg, `%timeit using_plus` takes 1.02ms, but `%timeit using_extend` takes 29µs which is significantly faster (**35 times faster**).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `for` loop:

```
list1 = [[], ['aa', 'aa'], [], ['bbbb', 'bbbb']]

l = []
for i in list1:
    l += i # or l.extend(i)

print(l)
# ['aa', 'aa', 'bbbb', 'bbbb']
```

Alternatively you can use a list comprehension:

```
[i for subl in list1 for i in subl]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iteratively combine the lists into one list:

```
from functools import reduce
list1 = [[], ['aa', 'aa'], [], ['bbbb', 'bbbb']]

reduced = reduce((lambda x, y: x + y), list1)
print(reduced)  # prints ['aa', 'aa', 'bbbb', 'bbbb']
```